# How to make the scanner read string characters like , - , / , *

Tags: java

I need to make my scanner read characters and number?

This code only ready numbers>>>

Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in) ;

I need it to read a + , a letter, etc...

Comment: Post what you've attempted.

Comment: Instead of using `nextInt()`, use `next()` or `nextLine()`.

Comment: Read the documentation and choose what you need: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Why is this marked as "Javascript"? Javascript is NOT Java, it's a completely different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can Use next() or nextLine() for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this

```
String letter = input.next();
```

or you can use it like this,

```
String text = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [next()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_next.htm) for this purpose.